# What would cause contextual filter settings NOT to save?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view in Drupal using a contextual filter.  I save the changes about what to do when a value is passed.  After I hit save, everything revers back as if nothing ever happened.

Has anyone seen this before? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the same Views Display after saving? Try disabling javascript in your browser and try to save the changes (you'll see really long forms, not pretty).

Comment: or maybe you have to break the lock. Sometimes due to simultaneous edition, the views get locked and the changes are not applied. Can you see any message saying the views are locked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the "simple" answer worked. I deleted the filter and added it back.  I'm not sure if I configured it wrong to begin with or if something "bigger" was at play.